# JavaFX : How to retrieve the Menu's subMenu ContextMenu instance

Tags: menu, javafx-8, contextmenu

I am trying to get the Menu's submenu ContextMenu instance. Is there a way to get that? I actually want to add some event filters on the submenu ContextMenu.

I tried getting the ContextMenu as below.

```
Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
menu.getItems().addAll(...); // Will be added dynamically

menu.setOnShown(e->{
   ContextMenu contextMenu = menu.getItems().get(0).getParentPopup();
   contextMenu.addEventFilter(..., ...);
});
```

How can I ensure that I set the event filter only once to the context menu?
Please note that the menu can be an item in MenuBar or as an item in Menu itself.

Comment: Your example seems to be incomplete. Where do you add your `"Menu"` to an instance of a `ContextMenu`

Comment: And did you consider that your call of `getItems()` within the lambda does not refer to the `getItems()` of the `menu`-instance?

Comment: @OlofKohlhaas, sorry it's a typo mistake of not including menu.getItems() in lambda. I corrected it. Regarding your first question, I assume you didn't get my actual question. My question is about the submenu's contextmenu. We will not set the contextmenu for submenu. It is internally handled by JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that menu can be a MenuBar or Menu. So it depends on how deeply the menus are nested and whether `getItems().get(0)` could also return a MenuItem.

So the following code might be a solution to your first question:

```
menu.getItems().get(0).getParentMenu().getParentMenu().getParentPopup();
// or
menu.getItems().get(0).getParentMenu().getParentPopup();
// or...
```

Related to your second question: You have to memorise which EventHandlers have already been added, for example in a collection. Or use one of the so called convenience methods which you are already using with `menu.setOnShown`.